# why is python global scope affected by local scope operations?

Tags: python, scope

I thought that changes to variables passed to a python function remain in the function's local scope and are not passed to global scope. But when I wrote a test script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from numpy import *

def fun(box, var):
    box[0]=box[0]*4
    var=var*4
    return 0

ubox,x = array([1.]), 1.
print ubox,x
fun(ubox,x)
print ubox,x
```

The output is:

```
[myplay4]$ ./temp.py 
[ 1.] 1.0
[ 4.] 1.0
```

The integer variable x is not affected by the operation inside the function but the array is. Lists are also affected but this only happens if operating on list/array slices not on individual elements.

Can anyone please explain why the local scope passes to global scope in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to realize is that when pass an object to a function, the function does not work with an independent copy of that object, it works with the same object. So any changes to the object are visible to the outside.

You say that changes to local variables remain local. That's true, but it only applies to changing variables (i.e. reassigning them). It does not apply to mutating an object that a variable points to.

In your example, you reassign `var`, so the change is not visible on the outside. However you're mutating `box` (by reassigning one of its elements). That change is visible on the outside. If you simply reassigned `box` to refer to a different object (`box = something`), that change would not be visible on the outside.

Comment: so you are saying that integers cannot be changed? Because what you are saying is not valid for integers.

Comment: @manu-fatto Excuse me? I said that reassigning a variable will not be visible on the outside. That's perfectly valid for integers. I also said that mutating objects is visible on the outside. That's also valid for integers by vacuous truth (i.e. integers can't be mutated).

Comment: Ok, you are saying that integers are immutable and... (after quick check) you are right! What is strange is the syntax  n+=1 which I thought was changing the integer n.

Comment: @manu-fatto The thing about `+=` is that it can either be a shortcut for reassignment (`n = n + 1`) or a mutating operation depending on whether or not the given type defines an `__iadd__` method. For integers `x += y` is a shortcut for `x = x + y`.

Comment: This is odd. However I got convinced that integer variables are references by the following test: (10 is 5*2) == True, (1000 is 500*2) == False.

Answer (score 2):

In your function

```
def fun(box, var):
    box[0]=box[0]*4
    var=var*4
    return 0
```

both `box` and `var` are local, and changing them does not change their value in the calling scope. However, this line:

```
box[0]=box[0]*4
```

does not change `box`; it changes the object that `box` refers to. If that line were written as

```
box = box[0]*4 + box[1:]
```

then `box` in calling scope would indeed remain unchanged.

Comment: So you are saying that box is not an array but a reference to an array?

Comment: That is correct. The line in question isn't quite an actual assignment to a local variable; it's really syntactic sugar for the method call `box.__setitem__(0,box[0]*4)`.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with scope at all.

You're passing an object into a function. Inside that function, that object is mutated. The point is that the variable inside the function refers to the same object as in the calling function, so the changes are visible outside.

Answer (score -2):

This does not depend on scope. It depends on how Python copies objects. For this respect, there are three kind of objects: scalars, mutable objects, immutable objects.

Scalars are copied by value, mutable objects are copied by reference and immutable objects are probably copied by reference but since you cannot modify them there is no implication.

Scalars are fore example all numeric types. Immutable are: strings and tuple. Mutable are: lists, dictionaries and other objects.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say that there are scalar values and that they are copied by value? I *never* think of "pass by value" in Python.